# RSS link in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss

I need to add a link to a rss page but i don't know how

```
def index
    @boxes = Box.paginate :page => params[:page], :order => "boxes.id desc", :per_page => 5,
                       :include => [:suppliers, :manufacturer]
    @page_title = 'Catálogo'

respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.xml  { render :xml => @boxes }
  format.rss  { render :layout => false }
end
end
```

the url to access is `http://localhost:3000/catalog.rss` but i don't know how to make it like this `<%= link_to 'Canal RSS', :action => 'index' %>`

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3951235/how-do-i-make-an-rss-atom-feed-in-rails-3?rq=1 It will help you for sure.

Answer (score 0):

In your routes.rb, you add the route first:

```
get 'catelog' => '<YOUR_CONTROLLER_NAME>#index', :constraints => {:format => :rss}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Canal RSS', catelog_url %>
```

`catelog` is the route prefix. You can run `rake routes` to see it.

Comment: I have to redirect to catalog/rss i'am trying with `get 'catelog' => 'catalog#rss', :constraints => {:format => :rss}` but it raises a template missin error.